# Return a single element instead of an array in a GraphQL query

Tags: graphql

Consider the following GraphQL query:

```
{
  entries {
    ...on posts_default_Entry {
      image {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will return the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "entries": [
      {
        "image": [
          {
            "id": "11010"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, since the `image` field is limited to 1 image, it doesn't make sense for it to be an array. I would prefer that the query returned the following instead:

```
{
  "data": {
    "entries": [
      {
        "image": {
          "id": "11010"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so. If you think about it, assets are always an array so treat them consistently as such, even if you've set a limit of one. If the backend limit changes, it won't screw with your setup, either.